# How I can Make Schema for Tables (Client, Companies and Users)

Tags: mysql, database

I am developing a program in PHP and I need to create MYSQL Schema for the following tables

1. Users
2. Clients
3. Companies

**My Requirements are**

1. A Client may have many companies and a company must belong to a client
2. Client can be able to login into the application as a user
3. A Company may have many users and each user can to login to an application
4. There is a superuser, which does not belong to any client|company but still can be login into the application

To handle the login system, I introduced a table users and created the schema as given below

```
table: clients
id as PK
name

table: companies
company_id as PK
name
client_id as FK

table: users
id as PK
company_id as FK
client_id as FK
```

is this ok? the way I am created the schema.

Comment: What does client_id in the users table do?

Comment: As a client himself can login into the application, If a client is login into the application, then I want to show all companies that belong to him, that is why I put the client id into the user's table. @radocaw

Comment: Is `users.company_id` really a PK? Shouldn't it be a FK to `companies`?

Comment: @Barmar you are right, users.company_id is FK not a PK.

Comment: The `users` table needs a `username` column